# How to draw a picture by using tikz as backgroud of a character?

Tags: tikz-pgf, characters, cjk

I am writing some Chinese character and hope to draw simple pictures by tikz and use it as background of this chinese characters. In a short I'd like to get some results as this picture (ignore the lower right noise):

[image]

How could I do? Thanks in advance. As an example for least workable code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[CJKnumber]{xeCJK}
\setmainfont{KaiTi}

\begin{document}
\Huge 明月出天山
\end{document}
```

Comment: How is the grid defined? What are its properties?

Comment: Note: `CJKnumber` option is invalid for latest versions of `xeCJK`. It is obsolete. Use `zhnumber` package if you need CJK numbers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Basic grid behing the character is shown, also there is a new command added `\Grid{}`, to insert the needed glyph inside a specific grid:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setCJKmainfont{KaiTi}
%
\newcommand\Grid[1]{%
 \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
  \draw[xstep=1ex,ystep=1ex,help lines] (-1ex,-1ex) grid (1ex,1ex);
  \node[inner sep=0pt] (char) at (0,0) {#1};
 }%
}
%
\begin{document}
%
\Huge 明月出天山
%
\Huge 明月出天\Grid{山}
%
\end{document}
```

The output is as follows:

> [image]

---

### Update

If a more nested grid is needed, one could apply a new parameter to the definition of `\Grid{<step>}{<glyph>}`, so modifing the command as:

```
\newcommand\Grid[2]{%
 \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
  \draw[xstep=#1 ex,ystep=#1 ex,help lines] (-1ex,-1ex) grid (1ex,1ex);
  \node[inner sep=0pt] (char) at (0,0) {#2};
 }%
}
```

Gives for `\Grid{1}{山}` and `\Grid{0.5}{山}`:

> [image]

Comment: Since our answers are basically the same and you answered first, would you consider adding to your answer the definition of a command (as in my answer), so I can delete my answer?

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina Yes, sure.

Comment: Answer deleted and +1 to your answer :-)

Comment: Would you mind to tell me how to get the font of `KaiTi` ? I only have `Kaiti SC` and `Kaiti TC` which mean `简体楷体` and `繁体楷体` respectively, I feel `KaiTi` and `Kaiti SC` are basically the same thing, just wondering how to get it since I can not find it even on `dafont.com`

Comment: @http8086 Heya! I didn't get (i.e. install manually) the font from anywhere, I simply used `\usepackage{xeCJK}` and `\setCJKmainfont{KaiTi}`and let MikTeX compile and download such packages on-the-fly

Answer (score 7):

Using Andrea L. and Gonzalo Medina's solution we may get weird result of CJK puncuations. There are some problems in the previous solutions:

- The position of grid should be relative to the base point of the character.
- The width and height of the grid should be both `1em`, not `2ex` (characters are square in most CJK fonts).
- The grids should be aligned.
- The bounding box of the picture should be slightly smaller than the grid lines, since the line width is not ignorable.

PGFTricks's solution may be also problematic about puctuations.

Here is an improved version of Andrea's solution which carefully handles the depth of the glyphs and the bounding box.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{KaiTi}

\usepackage{tikz}

% \grid for a single character
\newcommand\grid[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(char.base)]
  \path[use as bounding box]
    (0,0) rectangle (1em,1em);
  \draw[help lines,step=0.5em]
    (0,0) grid (1em,1em);
  \draw[help lines,dashed]
    (0,0) -- (1em,1em)  (0,1em) -- (1em,0);
  \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=base west]
    (char) at (0em,\gridraiseamount) {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}}

% \gridraiseamount is a font-specific value
\newcommand\gridraiseamount{0.12em}

% \Grid for a CJK string
\makeatletter
\newcommand\Grid[1]{%
  \@tfor\z:=#1\do{\grid{\z}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Huge
\xeCJKsetup{PunctStyle=plain}

明月出天山，苍茫云海间。

\Grid{明月出天山，苍茫云海间。}

% We use a dash to test \gridraiseamount
\grid{—}

\end{document}
```

[image: result picture]

Comment: I've also noticed that inside the definition of `\grid` the argument describing the step of the help lines could be implemented like: `\grid[2]...\draw[help lines,step=#1 em]`, just to know.

Comment: @AndreaL. Yes, that's possible. For Chinese characters, the grid is usually used to help children to learn to write. There're usually only two forms of girds, calld the “田” grid (田字格) and the “米” grid (米字格, the grid in my solution).

Comment: Thanks for the delucidation, this is something new that I've learned on chinese typography now, because I've always thought that at school grids weren't needed; it's interesting.

Comment: Thanks Andrea, PGFTricks and Leo! :) This helps a lot. I thinks the key points of this problem is [baseline=(char.base)] when define the picture. So glad to know this place and to know these warm heart friends.

Answer (score 5):

With PSTricks.

### Version 1

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[overlap,CJK]{ruby}

\newpsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=0pt,subgriddiv=1,gridcolor=lightgray}

\renewcommand\rubysep{-0.1ex}
\newsavebox\IBox

\newcommand\prepare[2][10]{\sbox\IBox{\raisebox{\depth}{\psscalebox{#1}{#2}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{min}
\prepare{\ruby{忍}{にん}\ruby{者}{じゃ}}
\psset{xunit=\dimexpr\wd\IBox/2,yunit=\dimexpr\ht\IBox/2}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](2,2)
    \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}
\end{pspicture}
\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Version 2

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[overlap,CJK]{ruby}

\newpsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=0pt,subgriddiv=1,gridcolor=lightgray}

\renewcommand\rubysep{-0.1ex}
\newsavebox\IBox

\newcommand\prepare[2][10]{\sbox\IBox{\raisebox{\depth}{\psscalebox{#1}{#2}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{min}
%\prepare{\ruby{忍}{にん}\ruby{者}{じゃ}}
\prepare[15]{犬}
\psset{xunit=\dimexpr\wd\IBox/2,yunit=\dimexpr\ht\IBox/2,linecolor=lightgray}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](2,2)
    \psline(2,0)(0,2)
    \psline(2,2)
    \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}
\end{pspicture}
\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

[image]