# Creating symbols in TikZ that mimic the characters in the fonts *Ultima Underworld II* and *Dungeon Master*

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts

- I want to create some symbols in TikZ.
- The symbols should mimic the character set of two very specific fonts.
- The fonts are called *Ultima Underworld II* and *Dungeon Master*.
- I attached some pictures that show the look of the fonts.
- I want to use the symbols within the normal text later.

[image: runes of ultima underworld 1 and 2]

[image: another example]

Comment: TikZ is for graphics. You are asking about using a particular system font.

Comment: Use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, assuming the fonts are publicly available. They allow you to use any system font.

Comment: I would like to use *Tikz + miktex with pdflatex*. thank you for asking. http://bfy.tw/HJ0Z

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ and because you are being rude in the comments.

Comment: Sorry for this. I have added the info "I am not looking for fonts, but I am looking for Tikz." to be sure that it will specific. thank you again.

Comment: If you set up your document font you can also use it with TikZ just like you can use it in a regular text.

Comment: Thank you at lot for your interests and recommendations, but I desire Tikz and not fonts, please.

Comment: Why though? Why recreate font shapes with TikZ and not use the font directly? You could use Inkscape to trace the outline of the characters and export to TikZ code.

Comment: (because I want "no fonts" as mentioned, please again, just tikz, please.) Yeah, it looks fairly possible, i.e. to create using Inkscape and then to export Tikz, sounds a possible method. thank you

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). Yes it is possible to build those directly in `tikz`. But, it would be helpful if you made an attempt at doing one of them and then people here could help you when you run into specfic issues.

Comment: I massively edited the question. If you are not happy let me know.

Comment: Your bfy.tw/HJ0Z is very rude in my opinion. Maybe apologize and start over. I saw this *after* I wrote the answer.

Comment: *"I want to use it in normal text later"* and *"no it's not about fonts!!!"* and puts font pictures and asks for how to do it with MikTeX :)

Comment: @percusse I edited the question yesterday. The OP did not react yet. I guess that the OP has no clue what he is asking and confuses the terminology.

Comment: " Yes it is possible to build those directly in tikz." is very positive. More importantly, my sincere apology, concerning the link http://lmgtfy.com about fonts (rather than Tikz).

Answer (score 4):

- Here's a simple code example.
- Is that what you mean?
- The code is far from optimal but maybe it helps you to ask a more specific question.
- I do not know if `baseline=(char.base)` would be better/more appropriate than `baseline=0` (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133638) for example).

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Code is loosely based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295360/    

% DRM --> Dungeon Master Runes
% 'em' is a length unit in LaTeX that is relative to the current font.
% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/ for (much) more information

\newcommand\DMRAn{% <-- needed
\tikz[x=0.75em,y=0.75em,baseline=0]
\draw(0,0)--(0,1)--(0.7,0.5)(0,0.5)--(0.7,0.0);% <-- needed
}

\newcommand\DMRBet{% <-- needed
\tikz[x=0.75em,y=0.75em,baseline=0]
\draw(0,0)--(0,1)--(1,0.75)--(0,0.5)--(1,0.25)--(0,0);% <-- needed
}

\begin{document}
ABC \DMRAn\ DEF \DMRBet\

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Maybe you can later combine this with [Simulating hand-drawn lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39296) to have a handwritten look :).

Comment: Exactly OK, Thank you Dr. Manuel Kuehner, It is awesome and impressive quality answer! No need to be stuborn with fonts, just Tikz method is nothing wrong or a crime.  I would give all possible stars if it was possible, so much efforts you give to help people on Tex Stackexchg. Thank you for considering  my post i.e. using Tikz (despite all Fonts method recommendations of many users (e.g. Xelatex,...))  Thank you a lot for your time and very high quality of answers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Better luck next time :)

Comment: Hopefully, there will be better answer quality, because you were the single accurate answer. Many thanks !

Comment: @linux432532 you might consider a) accepting the answer and b) dialing down your tone